# Why this code is not writing anything in the text file?

Tags: python, urllib2, lxml, mechanize

I am having problems with this code as it is doing everything OK apart from writing the outputs in the "f file". Could anyone help me with this?

The problem is with this line: f.write(blog +' '+ authority +'\n')

```
        try:
            response = br.open(buyer)
            tree = html.fromstring(response.read())
            blogs = tree.xpath('//div/ul/li[@class="sidebar-item"]/a/@href')
            for blog in blogs:
                if '.blogspot.com' in blog:
                    try:
                        response = br.open(blog)
                    except HTTPError, e:

                        if 'http://www.blogger.com/create-blog.g?defaultSubdomain=' in e.read():
                            try:
                                response = br.open( 'http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/links?site=' + blog )
                            except Exception:
                                response = br.open( 'http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/links?site=' + blog )
                            tree = html.fromstring(response.read())
                            authority = int (tree.xpath('//span[@class="metrics-authority"]/text()')[1].strip())
                            if authority>1:
                                print blog
                                print 'This blog is ready to be registered'
                                print authority
                                f.write(blog +' '+ authority +'\n')
                        else:
                            print ''
        except Exception:
            print ''
print 'Finished'
f.close()
```

Comment: is it giving an error, or just not writing?

Comment: Just not writing nothing there whereas in the terminal, I can see the output

Comment: You should be getting a **`ValueError`** in `f.write(blog + ' ' + authority + '\n')` because **`authority` is an `int` and you can't add that to a `str`**.  It's either not entering that branch, or you made a typo posting it here, or it's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

When you're trying to do

```
f.write(blog +' '+ authority +'\n')
```

Python is throwing a **`ValueError` because you can't add an `int` and a `str`**.  You're also **catching *every* exception which is ill-advised.**  Change the offending line to convert `authority` to a `str`:

```
f.write(blog +' '+ authority +'\n')
```

And you should be okay.  Get rid of the blanket `except` clause and only catch specific exceptions that you want to catch.  While you're developing this code, I would recommend you don't catch any any exceptions just so you can tell why things are going wrong.

Comment: I am really new at Python so please, could you explain me what to use instead of the try-except structure?

Comment: @alexgarciab The `try` is OK, but you are catching `Exception`, which means everything.  If there is a specific exception you want to catch (say, `TypeError` or `ValueError`), you should put that instead.  That way you won't accidentally barrel through an error you wanted to handle differently.